# Chat Architecture: Real time presence notification

Tags: architecture

I would like to better understand how does the presence notification mechanism works in a large scale chat, like gtalk and facebook chat.

I saw some videos and read articles about these two chats, but I didn't understand how the presence notification is working:
If I am entering the chat - how does the server knows who should be notified?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your status is send and stored in the backend when you open the app.
Maybe they also implemented some sort of heartbeat algorithm which sends a "I am online!" message every x seconds. If the heartbeat is not send anymore you are automatically marked as offline.

If someone else opens the app they pull the latest status of their list/friends.